# Teamviewer Keeps losing connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, teamviewer, centos-7

My remote session to a Linux box keeps losing it's team viewer connection.

It was working fine last week and now it keeps breaking.

**This is what it looks like.**

[image]

**I can ping the Linux Box without issues.**

[image]

I tested the Ethernet cable on another machine, that's not the issue.

I have un-installed and re-installed teamviewer but that did not help either.

Has anyone experienced anything like this before and how can i resolve it.

If anymore info is needed just let me know I'll add it below here.

Comment: Changing it from a static IP to a Dynamic one seemed to resolve the issue for now, seems like it's a configuration error on the Linux machine will vote to close this question.